# connection strings of database in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm using visual studio 2010 and creating database with sql server 2008.
i have created a microsoft sql server database in my windows 7 laptop and now a pc with windows xp is trying to connect to my windows 7 laptop database. (note: im using windows authentication for the database)

So here's the question.

Do i need to add data source in the windows xp application? how about the connection strings?
i get the error 26: error locating server/instance specified when i tried to connect from other pc.
And what settings i need to configure to allow other pc to connect to my database?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: check this link
http://goo.gl/YdRjX

and I will suggest that use the SqlServer authentication instead of using windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server Management Studio, right click the instance you want to connect to, go to Properties -> Connections -> Check "Allow remote connections to this server". You might also have to enable TCP/IP Protocol to be enabled thru Configuration Manager. You'll have to set your connection string on your XP client. See the [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) site for more info.